# tableview data source method is not getting called in navigation based application

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4

In my app control goes to numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection datasource methods but not to cellForRowAtIndexPath.
I am not able to find the problem,please any body give a solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check that `numberOfRowsInSection` is not returning zero.  Otherwise, show code.

Comment: are you using UItableview object or UitableviewController?

Comment: Thanks for the support.I have checked the rows in section and solved the problems.